# How to solve a calculation backwards

Tags: linear-algebra

So I am trying to use a calculation for a electronics project, and I won't bore you with the details. But anyways, the calculation goes like this:
$$V_\text{out} = \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} \cdot V_\text{in}$$

Now I know what $V_\text{out}$ is, what $R_1$ is and $V_\text{in}$, but I don't know what $R_2$ is.

I've tried almost $20$ different ways but I still can't figure it out. How would I solve for $R_2$ if:
\begin{align}
-V_\text{out} & = 5 \\
-R_1 & = 330 \\
-V_\text{in} & = 9
\end{align}

Comment: Could you confirm that the current statement is as you intend? (In particular, I suspect the values of the three constants are not supposed to be negated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} $$

$$R_2*V_{in}=V_{out}(R_{1}+R_{2})$$ Through cross multiplication. Now when you distribute and bring the terms with $R_{2}$ to the left, you get:

$$R_{2}*V_{in}-R_{2}*V_{out}=R_{1}*V_{out}$$
Factor out $R_{2}$ and divide accordingly:
$$R_{2}=\frac{R_{1}*V_{out}}{V_{in}-V_{out}}$$
Now you can plug in your values.

Answer (score 2):

Since $$\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} = 1-\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}$$
you have $$1-\frac{V_{\mathrm{out}}}{V_{\mathrm{in}}} = \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}$$
which you can rearrange for $R_2$ now that it only appears once.